# How to ask Postgres to report broken value?

Tags: postgresql

While running query I get error:

```
SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: timestamp out of range
  Where: SQL function "interval_length" statement 1
PL/pgSQL function order_item_suma(integer,tstzrange,boolean) line 7 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

is there a way to configure PG to report the value of timestamp which is out of range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the error message.

But with the default configuration of PostgreSQL, you will get the SQL statement that caused the error in the log. With that information you can find your answer.

The parameters you need:

- `log_min_error_statement` must be set to `error` or less.
- `log_min_messages` has to be `error` or less.

Comment: May you please clarify option which control logging of SQL statement?

Comment: Found the query, it is about 100lines ). Still do not know which value cause the problem, but in any case thank you.